# Reload page if modified on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I am trying to make the page reload if it has changed on the server, by ajax requesting the page's own url every second, and then checking if `textStatus` is `notmodified`.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $.ajax({
    url : window.location.pathname,
    dataType : "text",
    ifModified : true,
    success : function(data, textStatus) {
      if (textStatus !== "notmodified") {
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

However, the `textStatus` is always `success`

Comment: Check your server's caching headers.

Comment: I'm using [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) as web server.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with a random variable to avoid caching of the response, itself. Also, replace the `!==` with `!=`.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  $.ajax({
    url : window.location.pathname + "?" + (new Date()).getMilliseconds(),
    dataType : "text",
    ifModified : true,
    success : function(data, textStatus) {
      if (textStatus != "notmodified") {
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

If this doesn't work, try replacing:

```
location.reload();
```

With:

```
location.href = location.href;
```

This also depends on the server side script. It also needs to be sent from the Server Side... By setting the `no-cache` and `content-expires`.

Comment: That's insane. The whole point of the JavaScript is to see if the cached version is still fresh and only reload if it isn't! If you are going to change the URL to bust the cache, then you might as well get rid of the Ajax and just hit `location.reload()` regardless.

Comment: How do you check the cache then? It also needs to be sent from the Server Side... By setting the `no-cache` and `content-expires`. Will update that in the answer. Do you have a better one?

Comment: The code is attempting to make an If-Modified-Since or ETAGS request (with Ajax) and then looking to see if it comes back with OK or Not Modified (which would be sent from the server side code). Setting "no cache" would have roughly the same problems as changing the URL every time. It will stop there from ever being a cached version.

Comment: Surely it will return "notmodified" every request, since you're asking for (effectively) a different page every time.  What's it supposed to compare it to?  A different URL?